I want to realize that external keywords can call the interface or pass other methods to Onlyoffice's search function, can it be realized?
onlyoffice's search enhancement, I want to realize that external keywords can call the interface or pass other methods to Onlyoffice's search function,so that if there is an external keywords, onlyoffice can query directly and highlight the query result, can it be realized?
I introduced onlyoffice in vue.js.
I tried to read the official documentation, but it doesn't give an API to call the search function, and I wonder if I can use a plugin to implement it, and there is no plugin available.
